# How do I translate "with your bare hands"?

Tags: traduction

According to Linguee, I would translate "with your bare hands" as « à/avec vos mains nues ». But that seems very literal and what I want to translate is the sense of doing something yourself. For example, in a sentence like "I created this sculpture with my bare hands", the phrase "with my bare hands" gives a very I-did-it-myself effect and implies that the speaker put lots of effort in. I'm not sure if the literal translation into French works in the same way so if someone could help clarify that up that would be great.

Comment: Linguee is full of  mistakes. This is a good example of one.

Comment: Do you mean: without tools? So, it's either clay or sand or something soft, and not rock or marble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to be formal, you can say, with a bit of humour:

> *J'ai fait cette sculpture **tout seul avec mes petites mains**.*

e.g.:

> *Les tagliatelles, c'est moi qui les ai faites **toute seule avec mes petites mains**. J'ai étalé de la pâte pour douze œufs, précisa-t-elle en montrant la farine entre se doigts.*
> Carlo Lucarelli, *Une affaire italienne*, 2021.

> J'ai peint ça **tout seul avec mes petites mains**. [Alain Bresson](http://www.alain-bresson.com/sculptures.html#27), 2003

Otherwise:

> *J'ai fait cette sculpture **de mes propres mains**.*

> *J'ai crée cette sculpture **à la force de mes poignets**.* (Thanks @None)

Linguee translation is indeed literal so ***à main nues*** would perfectly work in a context where the expression is used literally too in English, e.g. ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/with-your-bare-hands)):

> He wrestled the lion to the ground with **his bare hands**.

Comment: « *J'ai fait cette sculpture **de mes propres mains.*** » correspond tout à fait au contexte, la première indiquerait plutôt une œuvre sans investissement personnel.

Comment: @Personne Ça se discute. L'expression *avec mes petites mains* sert pour moi plutôt à insister que c'est bien soi qui a réalisé la chose, peut-être pour répondre à une incrédulité. Je ne perçois pas d'idée de manque d'investissement personnel.

Comment: « De mes propres mains » renvoient à l'écoute du toucher, à la sensibilité de la conscience source de l'art où chaque œuvre est unique, « Avec mes petites mains » implique un jugement sur ce que l'on vit qui dénote une intervention du cortex et de ses concepts/formatages, ce qui débouche sur un artefact artisanal reproductible.  J'ai suivi/écouté mes mains vs mes mains on fait quelque chose (être contre avoir).

Comment: "par mes petits mains" fait féminin et créations enfantines, franchement. Mais, que sais-je moi? Pauvre anglophone que je suis...

Comment: @Lambie Féminin et créations enfantines ? *Un de mes potes en a acheté une fortement similaire (couleur, jantes), il habite du coté de la Vendée. Il a refais (sic) le joint de culasse tout seul avec ses petites mains dans son garage perso* [Forum-Peugeot](https://www.forum-peugeot.com/Forum/threads/galerie-des-membres-ins%C3%A9rez-vos-photos.93023/page-8)

Comment: Le mec dit: Il a refait la culasse **tout seul** + avec "ses petits mains". "Régarde, Maman, je l'ai fait tout seul". C'est dit d'une façon amusante de le dire.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, j'ai inclus ***tout seul***, fréquemment associé, à l'expression indiquée dans ma réponse. Je n'ai pas écrit ***par** mes petites mains* mais ***avec**...* et la phrase *C'est dit d'une façon amusante de le dire* n'est pas fausse, mais perfectible.

Comment: J'ai téléscopé deux phrases. C'est dit d'une façon amusante. ET C'est une façon amusante de le dire. Mais ta  phrase et la phrase du forum  font ironiques. Au lieu de te concentrer sur les petites gaffes que je fais avec mes petites mains tu pourrais reconnaîte qu'un mec disant ça, s'amuse.

Comment: Aussi, with one's bare hands suggère un gros effort.  Alors que ta traduction fait "mignon".

Comment: @Lambie Exactement, et les deux sont rendus. Ici l'ironie s'applique à soi-même. On dévalorise ironiquement ses propres "petites mains" alors que l'idée que l'on souhaite transmettre c'est au contraire que ses mains on bien travaillé, qu'un effort a été fait.

Comment: It  means: not using any tools. Sculptor use tools, unless they are working with clay.

Comment: @Lambie Tu es libre de proposer une réponse plutôt que de t'acharner sur la mienne.

Comment: @Lambie … pas tous les sculpteurs, en particulier ce qui coulent le bronze. On peut faire une sculpture en pierre, avec des outils traditionnels dans ses mains, il en sortira une œuvre unique, si c'est vraiment une œuvre réussie, l'artiste ne va pas parler de *ses mimines*, mais de la méthode employée manuellement, sans aide extérieure. — Et on peut réparer un moteur tout seul, avec ses propres outils, aussi bien qu'un professionnel en utilisant les procédures/méthodes ad hoc (qui peuvent demander de l'expérience, mais pas de créativité) …

Comment: …  sans créer une œuvre d'art, avoir suffisamment d'humour pour en parler avec ironie ? Pourquoi pas !

Comment: Si c'est vraiment très dur, "à la force de mes/des poignets" peut aller, l'anglais n'a pas l'expression équivalente, et en français on l'emploie aussi pour un effort non physique.

Comment: @None Je pense que à la force de mes poignets rend bien l'expression dans certains cas.